# Define the neighborhood of the point from a set, find internal and boundary points

Tags: general-topology

Given the set of natural numbers N and its subset M of numbers divisible by 7.
I need to define a neighborhood of a point from a subset of M, determine which point is internal, which is boundary, whether there are limit points and touch points.
How can I do that? I've got little time and I have minimal knowledge on this topic.
I figured out that the neighborhood of 21 would be (14,28). Is each point of the subset internal or 7 is not? Is 7 the boundary point?
Please be lenient to me, I am hearing about this topic for the first time. A would be grateful if you helped me.
(English is not my first language, sorry if I did any mistakes)